# Paste in the last column ( using variable in range) vba

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to copy one column from different excel sheets in one folder and paste in the last column of another excel sheet.
I have a problem using variable in range function for the destination worksheet column
I tried to use my i counter or the m as the last column
I appreciate if some one can help or give me guidance

```
Sub LoadColumn()

Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim val As Variant
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\ ....")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users.... .xlsm")

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
  
Set x = Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)
x.Sheets("example").Range("AF:AF").Copy
    
m = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column + 1

y.Sheets("summary").Range("i", "i").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
 
x.Close

i = i + 1

Next oFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using value assignment, rather than the clipboard):

```
Sub LoadColumn()

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim val As Variant
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\ ....")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users.... .xlsm")
        
    m = y.Sheets("Summary").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
      
    Set x = Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)
      
    y.Sheets("summary").Columns(m).Value2 = x.Sheets("example").Range("AF:AF").Value2
    
    x.Close
    
    m = m + 1
    
    Next oFile

End Sub
```